# Get a List of all Pushes with Git

Tags: git

How can I get a list of all `push` commands to or from a particular remote in `git`?

**For my case**, this would be OK to run on either the remote or the local repos.

**For bonus points**, how would I get a list of all **successful** `push` commands?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This method will only give you the successful pushes, but it may still be useful to you:

When you push to a branch in a remote that corresponds to one of your remote-tracking branches, and that push is successful, the remote-tracking branch will be updated.  In the default case where you've cloned from a repository this typically means that successful pushes to `master` in the remote `origin` will update the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.  Changes to `origin/master` are recorded in the reflog, so you can find the successful pushes with:

```
 git reflog show origin/master
```

For example, in one of my repositories, you'll see:

```
17f2303 refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: fetch origin: fast-forward
dd7e0ac refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}: fetch origin: fast-forward
1788ffe refs/remotes/origin/master@{2}: fetch origin: fast-forward
9763bbc refs/remotes/origin/master@{3}: fetch origin: fast-forward
058d0d6 refs/remotes/origin/master@{4}: fetch origin: fast-forward
921f0f1 refs/remotes/origin/master@{5}: fetch origin: fast-forward
8483afd refs/remotes/origin/master@{6}: update by push
18d527f refs/remotes/origin/master@{7}: update by push
1a0fc4a refs/remotes/origin/master@{8}: fetch origin: fast-forward
b19afc6 refs/remotes/origin/master@{9}: fetch origin: fast-forward
9253285 refs/remotes/origin/master@{10}: fetch origin: fast-forward
dfa664f refs/remotes/origin/master@{11}: fetch origin: fast-forward
30ee7c0 refs/remotes/origin/master@{12}: update by push
ad11e76 refs/remotes/origin/master@{13}: fetch origin: fast-forward
c337975 refs/remotes/origin/master@{14}: update by push
1ff03bd refs/remotes/origin/master@{15}: update by push
7fb1c8d refs/remotes/origin/master@{16}: fetch origin: fast-forward
452c8fa refs/remotes/origin/master@{17}: fetch origin: fast-forward
6c79a16 refs/remotes/origin/master@{18}: update by push
11d9c4a refs/remotes/origin/master@{19}: fetch origin: fast-forward
```

For example, you can tell from this that my most recent push updated `origin/master` from `18d527f` to `8483afd`.

If you need to rely on this, you'll need to stop the reflog from expiring after the default time (90 days IIRC).

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  FWIW, my reflog is showing entries from the last 9 months, and I haven't done anything to affect its behavior since I first installed.

Comment: @Clayton: That probably just means you haven't had `gc --auto` trigger yet; it'll expire reflogs older than that default 90 days. Just set `gc.reflogExpire` to `never` (or something larger) if you want things to stay that way.

Comment: For git learners: to set the reflog to never expire for all your local repos do: `git config --global gc.reflogExpire never` at the command line.

Answer (score 4):

Tortoise-Git for Windows has "Show RefLog" option https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-update.html, which includes date of commit.