# Time of commit pushed to remote

Tags: git

I would like to know when a given feature went online on my website. Is it possible with Git to understand when a commit was pushed to a specific remote?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way in git to obtain a push date for a given commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit)

Answer (score 2):

You can get some information with git reflog, but it doesn't have
timestamps.  The reflog only tracks your repo so you don't have information about
a change that was pushed to the remote from some other repo (e.g., by someone else).  (In that case, though,
you can know when you fetched it.)

```
$ git reflog origin/master | head -5
ed9877e refs/remotes/origin/master@{0}: pull origin: fast-forward
b63e5ed refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}: fetch origin: fast-forward
51cabd3 refs/remotes/origin/master@{2}: fetch origin: fast-forward
19e1764 refs/remotes/origin/master@{3}: fetch origin: fast-forward
5414418 refs/remotes/origin/master@{4}: update by push
```

But you can look into the logs yourself, there's a timestamp next to
the e-mail address, which is probably what you're looking for.

```
.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin$ grep 5414418 master | grep push
b298f510cfd690d090778567adf59d9e72787856 5414418836886a3d509902c7f40dbe4070b18b7d Someone <someone@somewhere> 1379350751 +0200      update by push
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Probably using git reflog --date=local master it gives you also the time when the action appened