# When a commit was pushed into a remote Git Repo

Tags: git, heroku

Is there a way to show *when* a particular commit was *pushed* into a remote repo?  In other words, I know who made a change (and when it was committed), but I don't know when it was pushed to my production environment in heroku (note: heroku just uses a git push to deploy)

Ideally, it would be something like:

`$ git remote myprodrepo show 201421b78ae73a21bc6045a78b4b5db5c54697e7`

and I could see when that commit actually got pushed into that repo.

note: the syntax above does not work, and is only there in an attempt to sort of show what I'm trying to accomplish.

(I hope this question makes sense - please ask questions if it doesn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Git don't record any log for those operations.

An intermediate [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html) like [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/) can keep such a record, but that may not be a good fit with your current setup.

Bside heroku releases [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20980958/6309) by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris), the one pure git way to get a recent record of *all* those operations (not just push) is [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12704702/6309), in the config of your remote git repo:

```
# required for a bare repo
git config core.logAllRefUpdates true

git reflog --date=local master
```

Comment: You are right.  This won't solve my problem, but looks to be very good information.  Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

[VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) is correct that Git itself does not track this information, but on Heroku, you should be able to get this information using the [`heroku releases`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#listing-release-history) command.

Sample output from the linked page:

```
Rel   Change                          By                    When
v52   Config add AWS_S3_KEY           jim@example.com       5 minutes ago
v51   Deploy de63889                  stephan@example.com   7 minutes ago
v50   Deploy 7c35f77                  stephan@example.com   3 hours ago
v49   Rollback to v46                 joe@example.com       2010-09-12 15:32:17 -0700
```

Note that `v51` shows when `de63889` was deployed to Heroku.

You can then use, e.g., `heroku releases:info v51` to get detailed information on this release:

```
=== Release v51
Change:      Deploy de63889
By:          jim@example.com
When:        7 minutes ago
Addons:      deployhooks:email, releases:advanced
Config:      MY_CONFIG_VAR => 42
             RACK_ENV      => production
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes; I do know this is available, but it's with branches, etc it can be a little bit hard to tell when a commit actually ended up in production.  In other words, a release might be made up of 20+ commits before it is pushed (it might have been the 9th in the series that had the bug).