# Find out when commits were pushed to git/github?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have a set of commits where I'd like to find out when they were actually pushed upstream.  It's a github enterprise server which I own, and someone committed a bunch of code, do to the nature of git I have to trust their timestamps.  I would instead like to see when the code was actually pushed upstream, or when pushes upstream ever happened.

In particular if I could see when all commits were pushed at what point it'd be awesome.  I've googled around and closes I can see is finding data using commit dates not push dates.

Comment: reflog ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit

Comment: So sadly I think that will only give me updates in the future I've got one in the past I'm looking for.

Comment: Right.  There's a chance you might be logging all ref updates on the server already.  If not, you are out of luck unless there is a github specific thing.

Comment: https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/admin/articles/viewing-push-logs/ doesn't show any timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) is what you want. Specifically you want to look for a [PushEvent](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) which will have an array of commits that were pushed. So if there were 5 or 10 commits pushed at once, they'll all belong to the same PushEvent.