# How to know when a commit was pushed to a remote repository on GitHub?

Tags: github, timestamp, push, git-commit

I am working on a project where I need to know when exactly a commit was pushed to a remote repository on Github. Using the git APIs and commands I can only find the commit's '`authored_date`' and '`committed_date`', which represent the time of the commit at the local repository.

I tried the approaches presented in this question: [Is there a way in git to obtain a push date for a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit). They only work when a commit was pushed from the same local machine, while I need them for commits in a cloned projects.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way in git to obtain a push date for a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit)

Comment: In that question, the answers do not describe a way of getting a push date for a specific commit. Second, they only show the pushes done from the machined being used. Please, reconsider my question as I see that it is not a duplicate of that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with [List Repository Events](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#list-repository-events)

For example:
https://api.github.com/repos/JetBrains/kotlin/events

It returns all the events for the repository.
Look there for the event with `type="PushEvent"` containing your commit SHA in the `payload/comits/sha`

This approach has some limitations:

- you can not request filtered events by type, you are only able to fetch them all and filter them on your side
- Only events created within the past 90 days will be included in timelines (according to GitHub doc)
- you have to care about pagination if you have massive events on your project