# Is there a possibility to find out at what date/time a commit was pushed to git origin Repo?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am using intellij git and in `Log` tab, I can see the commit message, committer name and commit date.

My question is, how to find out, when a commit was pushed to central / origin repo?

Comment: this is regarding git https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way in git to obtain a push date for a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the push time in IntelliJ UI, as there is no simple way to get this from git.

[Is there a way in git to obtain a push date for a given commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit) explains how one could get the push date in command line git, but that requires some repository configuration first