# How to see the history of a remote git push

Tags: git, push

Let's say we are two people working on a project each sitting at a different location and commit our codes to a git repository. If  my colleague pushes something to the remote repository, is it possible to see when she has done that git push? I mean the date. e.g. for commit, you could use git log, how about the remote push?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795070/is-there-a-way-in-git-to-obtain-a-push-date-for-a-given-commit , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012768/git-inspect-time-at-which-commit-was-pushed , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357219/expose-the-date-a-commit-was-pushed-to-a-repository etc. Looks like you've got a number of options detailed in those questions :)

Comment: Thanks Albert. The first link was enough to do the trick. And sorry about the dublicate.